# compare two CGPDFDictionary

Tags: c++, compare, cgpdf, cgpdfdictionaryref

Is the a way to compare two CGPDFDictionaries?
There is a function memcmp, but it doesn't work for me, because dictionaries are in different memory cells.

Comment: have you found the way to compare them?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the **[CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDictionary/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction)** function ?

It seems like if you supply a callback function , it will be called for every key-value pair.

```
void CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction (
   CGPDFDictionaryRef dict,
   CGPDFDictionaryApplierFunction function,
   void *info
);
```

So you can pass your second dictionary ( say **dict2** ) as **info**.  In your **CGPDFDictionaryApplierFunction** you can see if the current **key** being enumerated is also in **dict2**